# Application of Central Limit Theorem with independent but non-identical distributions

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

> Suppose $Y:=(Y_j)_{j\in \mathbb N}$ is a sequence of indepedent random variables where $Y_j$ has probability mass function $f_j(y)=(2j+1)^{-1}$ for $y\in\{k/j\}_{k=-j}^j$. Show that 
>   $$S_n:=\sum_{j=1}^n \frac {Y_j}{\sqrt{n}}$$ converges in distribution as $n\to\infty$ and determine the limit.

My attempt:

$$\mathbb E(Y_j)=0$$ by symmetry.

$$Var(Y_j)=\sum_{k=-j}^j \frac{k^2}{j^2(2j+1)}=\frac{j+1}{3j}$$
then $$\sum_{j=1}^nVar(Y_j)=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{j+1}{3j}=\frac n3+\frac 13 \sum_{j=1}^n\frac 1j$$
how do I proceed from the above, especially the extra sum, to claim the following that 
$$S_n\sim N\left(0,\frac 13\right)$$
which version of CLT is this?

Comment: Have you tried checking the [Lindeberg condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindeberg%27s_condition)? (I do not know if this will work or not.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ factor in the definition of $S_n$ should make the variance come out as needed when taking the limit of n going to infinity.  It looks like it cancels out the first $n$ leaving $\frac{1}{3}$, and the extra sum will be multiplied by 0.  Have you taken that into account?  I hope this helps.

Comment: i don't have an answer for this question, the above is just my guess. i don't know whether it is correct in the first place.